# in diango1.10, set a time to do the signals.post_save.connection()

Tags: python, django

in diango1.10, when upload a image file from website, then the database will insert a record which has a item is "is_execute", if not this image file will be executed by a function. I use the signals.post_save.connetion(), but I don't want to do this immediately, I hope this function can be execute at  the midnight

```
def an_update(sender, instance, **kwargs):
#path = os.path.join('/', os.path.dirname(__file__),instance.headImg.name)
#print path
if instance.is_excuted == False:
    instance.is_excuted = True
    instance.final_score = 0.5
    path = os.path.join('/root/myweb_vipa/upload/upload/',instance.headImg.name)
    cmd = '/home/yunshen/Ammeter_detection/ammeter_detection '+path+" "+instance.headImg.name
    subprocess.call(cmd,shell=True)
    instance.save()
    return 0
```

signals.post_save.connect(an_update, sender = User)

Comment: Let's all cross our fingers and hope with you. — Now, care to share what you have done so far and where you are stuck?

Answer (score 3):

That is not what signals do.

Signals are just a way of decoupling logic. They do not run out-of-process; there is no way to defer them.

If you need this ability, you should use something like [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/).

Comment: I add the function an_update, I want to check the model at midnight and do the an_update to the all image files which haven't execute and I can't visit the Celery

Comment: That's good. Use Celery. Or a cron job that runs a management command.